# Count the number of values in a range that are not defined in a list

Tags: excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a table that contains details of all of our companies mobile phones. Next to this table, I need some basic stats like how many handsets of each OS there are.

Using `COUNTIF` I can work it all out, apart from `Other`. Is there a way of calculating the number of values that do not equal anything in a list of values?

This works for just 'not Android' -

```
=COUNTIF(Mobiles[OS], "<>Android")
```

But this does not work when trying to exclude all the major players -

```
=COUNTIF(Mobiles[OS], AND("<>Android", "<>BlackBerry", "<>iOS", "<>Windows"))
```

Does anybody know how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, it's just not very clever

=COUNTIFS(Mobile[OS],"<>Android",Mobile[OS],"<>Blackberry", Mobile[OS],"<>iOS",Mobile[OS],"<>Windows",)

Comment: Great, that does the trick. I agree it's not very clever though, shame on MS!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t count `Other`, instead count `All` and subtract `Specific` (as derived from COUNTIF).